# SQL Conditional JOIN column

Tags: sql, join, case, conditional-statements, coalesce

I want to determine the JOIN column based on the value of the current row.

So for example, my job table has 4 date columns: offer_date, accepted_date, start_date, reported_date.

I want to check against an exchange rate based on the date. I know the reported_date is never null, but it's my last resort, so I have a priority order for which to join against the exchange_rate table. I'm not quite sure how to do this with a CASE statement, if that's even the right approach.

```
INNER JOIN exchange_rate c1 ON c1.date = {{conditionally pick a column here}}

  -- use j.offer_date if not null
  -- use j.accepted_date if above is null
  -- use j.start_date if above two are null
  -- use j.reported_date if above three are null
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try logic like this:

```
INNER JOIN
exchange_rate c1
ON c1.date = coalesce(j.offer_date, j.accepted_date, j.start_date, j.reported_date)
```

The `coalesce()` function returns the first non-NULL value in the list.

Comment: thanks for this answer. It's a pity the question has been marked a duplicate of an unrelated cross table question, instead of this single table multiple field question.

Comment: @simo.3792095 . . . I voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 4):

The CASE statement could look something like this:

```
INNER JOIN exchange_rate c1 ON c1.date =
CASE
    WHEN j.offer_date IS NOT NULL THEN j.offer_date
    WHEN j.accepted_date IS NOT NULL THEN j.accepted_date
    WHEN j.start_date IS NOT NULL THEN j.start_date
    ELSE j.reported_date
END
```